# How to extract specific no. of character from dataframe column Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Like Left formula we Used in Excel same as I want to extract no. of character from Policy no. column based on Insurer column like.....

if insurer is HDFC then Extract only 10 character form the sting and
if insurer is tata then Extract only 7 character form the sting.
and **if insurer other than HDFC & tata then leave it as blank.**

***also see hdfc insure comes with lot of different name.***

How I will achieve this in python

| Insurer | Policy no. | *Expected OutPut* |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hdfc | 4509242332 | 4509242332 |
| Tata | tatadigitNational | tatadig |
| Hdfc ergo | 09082323ab12sd | 09082323ab |
| HDFC | nolanheroman | nolanherom |
| Tata | 97543007356 | 9754300 |
| Tata | pqrsequence2o202 | pqrsequ |
| Tata | 987654321 | 9876543 |
| HDFC health ergo | nolanheroman | nolanherom |
| Digit | 1733choola |  |
| star | naahiHonaar |  |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is define a new function that does the comparison and apply that to a new column (`Expected OutPut` in your example).

```
def f(row): 
    val = str(row['Policy no.'])
    return val[:10] if row['Insurer'] == "Hdfc" else val[:7]

df['Expected OutPut'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but now again I am facing issue as insure comes with different like Hdfc ....... and i want to keep blank field in expected output column for insurer other than tata & hdfc.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `np.select`

```py
df['out'] = np.select(
    [df['Insurer'].str.lower().eq('hdfc'),
     df['Insurer'].str.lower().eq('tata')],
    [df['Policy no.'].str[:10],
     df['Policy no.'].str[:7],],
    df['Policy no.']
    )
```

```
print(df)

  Insurer         Policy no. Expected OutPut         out
0    Hdfc         4509242332      4509242332  4509242332
1    Tata  tatadigitNational         tatadig     tatadig
2    Hdfc     09082323ab12sd      09082323ab  09082323ab
3    Hdfc       nolanheroman      nolanherom  nolanherom
4    Tata        97543007356         9754300     9754300
5    Tata   pqrsequence2o202         pqrsequ     pqrsequ
6    Tata          987654321         9876543     9876543
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but now again I am facing issue as insure comes with different like Hdfc ....... and i want to keep blank field in expected output column for insurer other than tata & hdfc.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is,

```
df['temp'] = df['Insurer'].map({'Hdfc':10, 'Tata':7})
df['Expected Output'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Policy no.'][:x['temp']], axis=1)
```

O/P:

```
  Insurer         Policy no. Expected Output  temp
0    Hdfc         4509242332      4509242332    10
1    Tata  tatadigitNational         tatadig     7
2    Hdfc     09082323ab12sd      09082323ab    10
3    Hdfc       nolanheroman      nolanherom    10
4    Tata        97543007356         9754300     7
5    Tata   pqrsequence2o202         pqrsequ     7
6    Tata          987654321         9876543     7
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but now again I am facing issue as insure comes with different like Hdfc ....... and i want to keep blank field in expected output column for insurer other than tata & hdfc.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
df['Expected OutPut'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Policy no.'][0:10] if x['Insurer']=='Hdfc' else x['Policy no.'][0:7], axis = 1)
print(df)

Insurer         Policy no. Expected OutPut
0    Hdfc         4509242332      4509242332
1    Tata  tatadigitNational         tatadig
2    Hdfc     09082323ab12sd      09082323ab
3    Hdfc       nolanheroman      nolanherom
4    Tata        97543007356         9754300
5    Tata   pqrsequence2o202         pqrsequ
6    Tata          987654321         9876543
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but now again I am facing issue as insure comes with different like Hdfc ....... and i want to keep blank field in expected output column for insurer other than tata & hdfc.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
df['Expected Output'] = np.where(df['Insurer']== 'Hdfc', df["Policy no"].str[:10],df["Policy no"].str[:7])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can easily do this by converting the dataframe to an array, then iterating through every row

```
array = df.to_numpy()

for row in array:
    #assuming you only have 2 columns, check to see if the insurer is Tata
    if row[0] == 'Tata':
        #slice string in the Policy column
        row[1] = row[1][:7]
#now, convert array back to df
pd.Dataframe(array, columns=['Insurer','Policy no.'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but now again I am facing issue as insure comes with different like Hdfc ....... and i want to keep blank field in expected output column for insurer other than tata & hdfc.